# Oracle SQL UNION ALL with NULL causes performance issues when trying to outer join the data

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-ebs

I am trying to build a query that returns the customers from Oracle and their notes. Unfortunately, the notes tables from which I am selecting the data do not have any 1-1 joins with the customers so I am joining the data by using the party id and looking for a particular string in the notes that contain the customer contract number.

What I want to do is to return the customer, contract and their note information if the notes exist and if the notes do not exist.

I know the code below is lengthy, but I am particularly interested in how to handle the very last bit of the code (so the code where I join with the notes info at the end). The issue that I have in the current version of the query is that if I join the FORCE_NOTE_GUAR and FORCE_NOTE_CUST subqueries by adding the UNION ALL with nulls, the performance is very very bad.

If I remove that UNION ALL the performance is good, however I only get the customers that do have the notes and I don't have the customers that do not have the notes.

I know that it is a long query and a long post so please ping me if I can give more info.

```
     SELECT QUERY_MAIN.*
,      FORCE_NOTE_CUST.NOTE_CREATION_DATE                                       AS FORCE_ACCEPT_DATE_CUST
,      FORCE_NOTE_GUAR.NOTE_CREATION_DATE                                       AS FORCE_ACCEPT_DATE_GUAR
,      FORCE_NOTE_CUST.ENTERED_BY_NAME                                          AS USER_FORCE_ACCEPT_CUST
,      FORCE_NOTE_GUAR.ENTERED_BY_NAME                                          AS USER_FORCE_ACCEPT_GUAR
,      FORCE_NOTE_CUST.NOTES                                                    AS NOTES_CUST
,      FORCE_NOTE_GUAR.NOTES                                                    AS NOTES_GUAR
FROM (SELECT HP.PARTY_ID
      ,      HCA_CUSTOMER.ACCOUNT_NUMBER                                        AS ACCOUNT_NUMBER
      ,      OKH.CONTRACT_NUMBER                                                AS CONTRACT_NUMBER
      ,      DECODE(OKP.ATTRIBUTE5, 'F', 'Y', 'N')                              AS CUSTOMER_FORCE
      ,      DECODE(GUAR_FORCE.FORCE_FLAG, 'F', 'Y', 'N')                       AS GUARANTOR_FORCE
      --------------------------------------------------------------------------
      FROM  ... customer tables) QUERY_MAIN
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
, (SELECT* FROM(SELECT JII.PARTY_ID                                             AS PARTY_ID
                ,      TO_CHAR(DECODE( JIHA.ACTION, 'Converted'
                               , SUBSTR(JNV.NOTES_DETAIL,1,2000)
                               , NVL( JNV.NOTES
                                    , SUBSTR( JNV.NOTES_DETAIL
                                            , 1
                                            , 2000))))                          AS NOTES
                ,      JNV.CREATION_DATE                                        AS NOTE_CREATION_DATE
                ,      NVL(PEP.FULL_NAME, FU_INT.USER_NAME)                     AS ENTERED_BY_NAME
                ----------------------------------------------------------------
                FROM    ... notes tables)
   WHERE  NOTES LIKE '%Guarantor acceptance manually progressed%'
   UNION  ALL
   SELECT NULL                                                                  AS PARTY_ID
   ,      NULL                                                                  AS NOTES
   ,      NULL                                                                  AS NOTE_CREATION_DATE
   ,      NULL                                                                  AS ENTERED_BY_NAME
   FROM   DUAL)                                                                 FORCE_NOTE_GUAR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
, (SELECT* FROM(SELECT JII.PARTY_ID                                             AS PARTY_ID
                ,      TO_CHAR(DECODE( JIHA.ACTION, 'Converted'
                               , SUBSTR(JNV.NOTES_DETAIL,1,2000)
                               , NVL( JNV.NOTES
                                    , SUBSTR( JNV.NOTES_DETAIL
                                            , 1
                                            , 2000))))                          AS NOTES
                ,      JNV.CREATION_DATE                                        AS NOTE_CREATION_DATE
                ,      NVL(PEP.FULL_NAME, FU_INT.USER_NAME)                     AS ENTERED_BY_NAME
                ----------------------------------------------------------------
                FROM   ... notes tables)
   WHERE  NOTES LIKE '%Customer acceptance manually progressed%'
   UNION  ALL
   SELECT NULL                                                                  AS PARTY_ID
   ,      NULL                                                                  AS NOTES
   ,      NULL                                                                  AS NOTE_CREATION_DATE
   ,      NULL                                                                  AS ENTERED_BY_NAME
   FROM   DUAL)                                                                 FORCE_NOTE_CUST
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Outer logic to select the appropriate notes
WHERE    1 = 1
AND   (( CUSTOMER_FORCE = 'N' AND FORCE_NOTE_CUST.PARTY_ID IS NULL)
      --If CUSTOMER_FORCE = 'Y'
      --If the customer has force accepted, we need to find the note 
      OR (    CUSTOMER_FORCE = 'Y'
          AND QUERY_MAIN.PARTY_ID              = FORCE_NOTE_CUST.PARTY_ID                      
          AND INSTR(FORCE_NOTE_CUST.NOTES, CONTRACT_NUMBER) > 0))
AND   (( GUARANTOR_FORCE = 'N' AND FORCE_NOTE_GUAR.PARTY_ID IS NULL)
      --If GUARANTOR_FORCE = 'Y'
          --If the guarantor has force accepted, we need to find the note
      OR ( GUARANTOR_FORCE = 'Y' 
          AND QUERY_MAIN.PARTY_ID              = FORCE_NOTE_GUAR.PARTY_ID   
          AND INSTR(FORCE_NOTE_GUAR.NOTES, CONTRACT_NUMBER) > 0));
```

Comment: I'm sure you could cut a lot of irrelevant columns (at least) out of that to give people something simpler to work with?

Comment: @TonyAndrews good point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `unions` with `nulls` and change Your query to `left join` version:

```
SELECT QUERY_MAIN.*,
       FORCE_NOTE_CUST.NOTES,
       FORCE_NOTE_GUAR.NOTES
  FROM QUERY_MAIN
  LEFT JOIN FORCE_NOTE_GUAR on FORCE_NOTE_CUST.PARTY_ID = QUERY_MAIN.PARTY_ID
                           and FORCE_NOTE_CUST.NOTES like '%'||CONTRACT_NUMBER||'%'
  LEFT JOIN FORCE_NOTE_CUST on FORCE_NOTE_GUAR.PARTY_ID = QUERY_MAIN.PARTY_ID
                           and FORCE_NOTE_GUAR.NOTES like '%'||CONTRACT_NUMBER||'%'
```

Comment: Yeah, this question is a good example of why the old join syntax was deprecated in favor of ANSI joins. For outer joins, ANSI style is much easier to read and understand.

Comment: Thank you!
I thought of using the left join initially but overcomplicated with AND/OR...